# Converting Play Framework Application to Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, playframework, converters, playframework-1.x

We have done a quick proof of concept web application using PlayFramework1.2 and now we would like to proceed for production release however one of the  concern is that Play Framework not enterprise compatible and wanted the application to be ported  over to Spring.

Any **tools or guidelines** for porting over playframework project to spring MVC ?

> Note: I'm saying not enterprise compatible because it seems Play1.x development been abandoned and no any new Play 1.x release recently. Also current Play framework 2.0 more focus on Scala rather than Java.

Comment: You should build the concept in the Play 2+ as it's stable for more than a year. What's more it is enterprise ready and is actively developed. There are huge differences between Play and Spring and I doubt if you'll find ANY resources about migration.

Comment: And it's not required to use Scala almost at all... all you need to learn is at least simplified Scala syntax for templates. In all other parts it will be just common Java framework.

Comment: yes , I agree play framework is stable, however I just concern about fear of upgrade as described in [rebellabs](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/play-framework-unfeatures-that-irk-my-inner-geek/). Looking for a framework which is efficient in the long-term

Comment: Well probably I won't convince you, but there's short story: Play 1.0 was very initial state, almost a draft, then devs made a lot of effort and created 1.2 which can be considered as first really fine product. After that Play 2+ appeared, which brings even more optimal solutions. Actually there are no problems with refactoring ie. from 2.0.0 to 2.1.x (and up) just cosmetic changes, which are always described. I can advice you the Play 2+ with clean conscience. And even if you'll decide to switch to Spring if ever will think about using Play again don't use 1.x anymore.

Comment: @biesior Thanks and I really appreciate for your input.

Answer (score 2):

As above posters mentioned Play 1.x was an initial draft. I was in your shoes contemplating whether to rebuild the app in Spring but I gave Play 2.x a chance and now I don't think I want to go for Spring at all. With every release Play is becoming more and more feature rich. I think before migrating to Spring you should give Play 2.1 a chance. Moreover if you need Spring for DI then you can actually mix Spring with Play 2.1 as well. See this demo app:

https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo

Hope that helps.